# If singletons are haecceities/haecceitic(al?), but there are singleton-minus sets, does that mean not everything has a haecceity?

Tags: properties, haecceities

I've seen a few times that [haecceities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haecceity) might be equated/conflated with singletons of the things that have them. For example, the SEP article on haecceitism [reports David Lewis as saying](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/haecceitism/#HaeHae):

> “So we get properties that are in no way qualitatively delineated, and some of these are haecceities of this- and other-worldly individuals. A unit set of an individual is one especially stringent haecceity. Also, for any individual and any counterpart relation, there is the set of that individual together with all its counterparts, and this is a less strict sort of haecceity.”

(I assume that "unit set" = "singleton.") [This article](https://www.academia.edu/2046923/Scotus_on_Universals_and_Individuation) seems to be an example of a similar (or the same?) thesis, and a Google search for {"singletons" "haecceities"} includes a result showing up as:

[image]

And intuitively, I get it, *X* seems related to {*X*} as an individual to its haecceity would be.

However, in some set theories ([Quine's](https://mathoverflow.net/a/117056/147890), my own,<sup>**{}**</sup> [Forster's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26028/695171)), there is not a proper class, but a set, of all singletons, which is less than the universe (or (co)universal set), i.e. there are elements such that they are not (can't) be contained by a singleton. In my own theory (I don't know about Quine's or Forster's), this phenomenon is extended to eventual doubleton-minus, tripleton-minus, ... generally, tupleton-minus sets; but anyway, **if singletons are haecceities, and some elements don't have singletons containing them, then do those elements not have haecceities?** Or is this a counterargument against equating/conflating singletons and haecceities? Because otherwise, if haecceities are "thisnesses" (by definition), it seems we could speak of "this" set, with respect to any identifiable set.

---

<sup>**{}**</sup>Mine does it like so: take the set of all sets with singletons above them *X*, have this *X* be well-founded, then negate the property of *X*'s elements for *X* itself (to block self-containment), and voila, *X* doesn't have a singleton above it. QED indeed...

Comment: Every set has a singleton containing it by an application of Pairing, right?

Comment: @user4894 in ZF(C), et, al., I would assume so, but if you waive pairing, or do whatever Quine or Forster do, I assume not.

Comment: Is the question about logistics?

Comment: @fkybrd it's about set theory and an interpretation of the concept of haecceities in terms thereof.

Comment: It is important to be able to use uncertainty to resolve a hypodox. How can haecceities be proven for all models without resolving hypodox?